# Tailwind intelliSense not working with Shadcn on Next js 13

Tags: next.js13

Since I Installed Shadcn my tailwind intellisense doesn't show suggestion anymore.
this is my tailwind.js.config file:
I'm working on a Nextjs 13 project with the 'app' strucure
Any help higly appriciated.

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    // "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  future: {
    hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true, //mobile devices will not show hover effect (touchscreen devices)
  },

  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        xs: "320px",
      },
      // .... //
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  darkMode: ["class"],
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
 
};
```

[image: this Is the output from talwind intellisense pluggin]

Comment: Same here, even after 3 months the problem still persist